# Build page from content type course - use views or custom code

Tags: views

I'm looking to build a page like the wireframe below and need help to decide if I should use views or custom code. I haven't really used views before but looks like it could be a nice way to build up the page and add additional functionality (filtering, paging, searching etc) at a later stage.

My concern is the layout and also the links. One titled 'learn more' that links to the actual node and the other 'enrol' which is a course module link.

Should I use view or just custom code in a module?

[image: wireframe]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear from your post on your knowledge of Views.  However if your referring to the 4 content boxes being shown in the sketch then Views is a great tool for doing this.

Regarding layout there is the functionality to return all fields you require in divs / classes etc and will be able to generate the look you wish.

Also links are no problem; in fields call up [content:path] - you can then add a 'custom text' field with your link

```
<a href='[path]' class="mybbutton">Link</a>
```

Views can general be viewed as a way of returning data from the database and present it how you wish.  enjoy!

Comment: thanks this was just the easiest. I suppose it was really just the first view I was creating in a very very long time. So content:path as well as global:text worked to create the layout required.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can achieve that using the [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) module

> The Panels module allows a site administrator to create customized layouts for multiple uses. At its core it is a drag and drop content manager that lets you visually design a layout and place content within that layout. Integration with other systems allows you to create nodes that use this, landing pages that use this, and even override system pages such as taxonomy and the node page so that you can customize the layout of your site with very fine grained permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this easily by using views using grid layout of 2 items in grid .you can also use grouping for grouping your fields and for learn more you can use Global: Custom text type learn more in text field use replacement pattern output this field as a link using node/[nid] but you have to include nid field also excluding from display

Answer (score 0):

As you are new to view I would suggest you to go with combination of views and Pannel 3 modules here is the tutorial to guide you: https://www.drupal.org/node/206792

one benefit of using views module in your scenario is you can customize html code inside a block by overwriting its theme file. Which gives you freedom to format your site look in the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Display all the fields you want to show in the course view page and "exclude" all the fields except the last one present in the display list.

Go to "Rewrite Results" section of last field which is not exclude from display.
Check "Rewrite the output of this field". Use the "replacement patterns" and design your view as you want.

Enjoy...